How can I stretch the figure's width beyond the margins to the page width?
I have this figure and I am trying to make it exceed the page margins to fit the literal width of the page or maybe 0.95% of the page width.

Below is the original code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.2em}}
\def\imagevspace{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
\def\cropa{5cm}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\vspace{0.1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}   
    \footnotesize{True Left} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\[-0.3cm]
    \footnotesize{Pred Left} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{True Right} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{Pred Right} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    % max t = 246
    
    % image1 t=0
    \def\time1{0}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image1.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);

    % image2 t=40
    \def\time1{0.16}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image2.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image3 t=70
    \def\time1{0.284}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image3.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image4 t=92
    \def\time1{0.365}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image4.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image5 t=120
    \def\time1{0.487}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image5.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image6 t=160
    \def\time1{0.650}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image6.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image7 t=190
    \def\time1{0.772}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image7.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image8 t=220
    \def\time1{0.894}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image8.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{x}
\label{fig:qualitative-mocap}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}

I tried using makebox as suggested by chatgpt but it doesnt work. I get the figure below. It now exceeds the page margins but everything is in one line. How can I fix it?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.2em}}
\def\imagevspace{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
\def\cropa{5cm}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\vspace{0.1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}   
    \footnotesize{True Left} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\[-0.3cm]
    \footnotesize{Pred Left} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{True Right} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{Pred Right} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    % max t = 246
    
    % image1 t=0
    \def\time1{0}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image1.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);

    % image2 t=40
    \def\time1{0.16}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image2.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image3 t=70
    \def\time1{0.284}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image3.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image4 t=92
    \def\time1{0.365}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image4.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image5 t=120
    \def\time1{0.487}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image5.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image6 t=160
    \def\time1{0.650}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image6.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image7 t=190
    \def\time1{0.772}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image7.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image8 t=220
    \def\time1{0.894}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image8.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{x}
\label{fig:qualitative-mocap}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


Your MWE doesn't reproduce showed image. However, its width seems that its width is equal to width of page. Please, check your MWE again and resolve image design. Why you use \subfloat? Your image doesn't have (sub) captions

@Zarko I am using overleaf and both the MWE are showing the correct figures

Overleaf is just editor, it hasn't any influence to compilation result, which gives corrupted image (all sub images are in one row).

Try \makebox[\textwidth}{\parbox{\paperwidth}{...}}

To long for comment:

It is entirely clear what you after
Your MWE doesn't gives result you show in your question
I guess that you looking for something like this:



However it is not clear:

why you for placement of your images use \subfloat
for what you need [remember picture] options for part of your images
where should start images in third and fourth row
etc.



MWE, which produce above figure:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains}

\usepackage[strict]{chngpage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-25mm}{-25mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {text width=#1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
    ]
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 8}
{
  \node[N=\linewidth/8, on chain]       (n1\i)  {\includegraphics {example-image-a}};
  \node[N=\linewidth/8, below=of n1\i]  (n2\i)  {\includegraphics {example-image-b}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

As you can observe, I didn't bother with cropping of your images. This can I add when will be more clear, what this image should present.
